# what does '#' mean in cpp code? here's a code for reference . I stuck at " char top = st.empty() ? '#' : st.top(); "

Tags: c++

```
bool isValid(string s) {
    stack<char> st;



    for(int i=0;i<s.length();i++) {
        char top = st.empty() ? '#' : st.top();
```

The code is the solution for 'Valid Parenthesis' on LeetCode.

Comment: `'#'` is a [character literal](https://en.cppreference.com/w/cpp/language/character_literal).

Comment: I don't know what "bugging out for a while" means. Please provide a [mcve], any error messages you are getting, and the desired vs. undesired behavior.

Comment: The `char top = st.empty() ? '#' : st.top();` line does this If `st` is empty initialize the variable `top` with the caracter #  otherwise initialize the variable top with the top item from the stack

Answer (score 3, accepted):

When you wrote:

```
char top = st.empty() ? '#' : st.top();
```

The above checks if `st` is empty. If `st` is empty then `top` is initialized with the **character literal** `'#'`. Otherwise, `top` is initialized with the character returned from `st.top()`.

Also, `'#'` is a **character literal**.

Comment: No that's not the same at all since `top` is out of scope at the end of the block.

Comment: Much better now. Thanks for the edit. Have an upvote.

Comment: @Bathsheba Thanks for pointing out the problem in my original version of the answer.